# "Bucket Fill" algorithm in Javascript or coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i'm writing a little coffeescript/js app that allows user to design icons ( 16x16 pixels or 32X32 pixels ).
The icon is actually a 2 dimensional array with color cells. A cell can have a color or be empty.

I want the user to be able to fill blank cells with a "bucket paint" tool.

It means that

- if the user clicks on a blank cell , all the cells that are blank next to the clicked cell with be filled with the choosen color , until it reaches a colored cell
- if the user clicks on a colored cell , all the cells that are next to the clicked cell and share the same color will be filled , but not the blank ones nor the colored ones ( with another color ).

The app already allows the user to fill cells one by one with a chosen color , or delete colored cells with a pen tool.

Any suggestions ?

(ps : i'm not using html canvas to draw )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is only 16x16 or 32x32 you can use a recursive solution:

Say your starting point is to change pixel x/y from color A to color B (A or B can be empty).

In pseudo code:

```
function floodfill(x,y,A,B) {
  if ((x<0) || (x>15) || (y<0) || (y>15)) return;
  if (get_color(x,y)!=A) return;
  set_color(x,y,B);
  floodfill(x-1,y-1,A,B);
  floodfill(x-1,y,A,B);
  floodfill(x-1,y+1,A,B);
  floodfill(x,y-1,A,B);
  floodfill(x,y+1,A,B);
  floodfill(x+1,y-1,A,B);
  floodfill(x+1,y,A,B);
  floodfill(x+1,y+1,A,B);
}
```

Comment: To makes things clear, you would call this as follows: `floodfill(clickX, clickY, originalColor, fillColor)`.  Presumably you have some way of identifying colors (including empty), and some method to fill a single pixel that would replace `set_color`, so it should basically be a drop-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what type of suggestions you're looking for, but you should take a look at flood fill algorithms.

Here it is on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: nice , link , thanks , i did not know that algorithm had a name.

Answer (score 0):

Allright , here is how i solve my problem in coffeescript.
It is an exemple using canvas.
the script should run on any page where there is a canvas element with a id of canvas , i had to create my own stack because of stackoverflow issues.

```
log = ->
  console.log arguments

class Point
  constructor:(@x,@y)->

class BucketFiller
  MAXITERATION:100000
  factor:1
  fill : (ctx,pixel, colCible, colRep)->
    P = []
    max = @MAXITERATION
    if @getColorAtPixel(ctx,pixel)!=colCible then return null
    P.push(pixel)
    while  P.length > 0 and max >=0
      --max
      currentpixel = P.pop()
      @fillRect(ctx,currentpixel.x,currentpixel.y,@factor,@factor,colRep)
      if @isInCanvas(ctx,currentpixel)
        if @getColorAtPixel(ctx,@up(currentpixel)) == colCible then P.push(@up(currentpixel))
        if @getColorAtPixel(ctx,@down(currentpixel)) == colCible then P.push(@down(currentpixel))
        if @getColorAtPixel(ctx,@right(currentpixel)) == colCible then P.push(@right(currentpixel))
        if @getColorAtPixel(ctx,@left(currentpixel)) == colCible then P.push(@left(currentpixel))
    return

  fillRect:(ctx,x,y,width,height,color)->
    ctx.fillStyle = color
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height)
    return
  down :(pixel)->
    return {x:pixel.x,y:pixel.y-@factor}

  up:(pixel)->
    return {x:pixel.x,y:pixel.y+@factor}

  right :(pixel)->
    return {x:pixel.x+@factor,y:pixel.y}

  left :(pixel)->
    return {x:pixel.x-@factor,y:pixel.y}

  getColorAtPixel:(ctx,pixel)->
    try
      imageData = ctx.getImageData(pixel.x,pixel.y,1,1)
    catch e
      return null
    return @rgbArrayToCssColorString(imageData.data)

  rgbArrayToCssColorString:(array)->
    result = "rgb(#{array[0]},#{array[1]},#{array[2]})"
    return result

  isInCanvas : (ctx,pixel)->
    result = ((0 <= pixel.x <= ctx.canvas.width) and (0 <= pixel.y <= ctx.canvas.height))
    return result

main=->
    buckfiller = new BucketFiller()
    log("start")
    canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas")
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    penPosition = new Point(2,10)
    fillColor = "rgb(255,0,0)"
    colCible = buckfiller.getColorAtPixel(ctx,penPosition)
    try
      buckfiller.fill(ctx,penPosition,colCible,fillColor)
    catch e
      log e

window.onload=->
  main()
```