# How can I color inside a rectangle Canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making an app that its very similar to Paint, where it has a button that draw lines, one that inserts rectangles, ellipses and etc. This app also has a bucket button, where if i click it, it should paint the area inside a rectangle/ellipse that is already inserted into the canvas.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: check out flood fill algorithms. [Here is a good article on them](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-paint-bucket-tool/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a flood-fill.

The HTML5 canvas does not provide this out-of-the-box, so you have to do this yourself.

1. use [`var imagedata = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29) to get an [ImageData](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-2dcontext-20110405/#imagedata) object which represents the raw pixel data of the canvas.
2. The RGBA values are in `imagedata.data` It is a one-dimensional array where each pixel is represented by four values. To get/set the color value of a specific pixel, use `imagedata.data[x + y * imagedata.width + offset]` where offset is 0, 1, 2 or 3 for red, green, blue or alpha.
3. Perform the [flood-fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm on the data
4. Write the modified imagedata structure back to the canvas using [`context.putImageData(imagedata, 0, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29).

Comment: How can I implement this algorithm

Comment: @Glund The wikipedia article explains it really well, in my opinion. There is also a good explanation in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313173/bucket-fill-algorithm-in-javascript-or-coffeescript/9313285#9313285).